# Do I need to have QGIS installed on a machine to make use of it's python libraries?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I'm trying to make a simple stand-alone app to expedite the production of some site plan maps for my work. The maps are very formulaic, and follow a set template every time. With the QGIS libraries, I believe this may be possible to implement for free. I was thinking of making a simple app in python that takes a few strings of input from the user to fill in the boxes in the form at the bottom of the map document, connects to our geodatabase and the parcels layer, zooms to a parcel with an ID specified by the user, and generates a map of it and the surrounding area

Would I need QGIS installed on the machine to actually do this, or would i be able to get away with just including the libraries and installing GDAL?

Answer (score 5):

PyQGIS is just the bindings for the C++ application.

So it uses the application through Python. So if you want to use the QGIS Python library then you need QGIS installed.

However once the application is created, QGIS is not always necessary. For example IntraMaps Roam is a python based client built on the QGIS libraries. QGIS is only needed on the application that does the compiling: https://github.com/DMS-Aus/Roam

Comment: thanks, is there a guide to making it so that you don't require QGIS after it's compiled? or is that default behavior? Sorry, I am still a novice at python

Comment: That is pretty advanced stuff, you would have to know what C++ libraries you require and how they are being use. No guide as it is really not common. Why not build the application as a plugin for QGIS? Definitely easier that way, especially if new to Python. The creator of Roam is a core developer of QGIS.

Comment: the idea was to make something very basic to give to the less technical planners so they could generate these very formulaic basic maps themselves and pull some workload off of the GIS team. IT seems very hesitant to even install QGIS on my computer (ESRI Shop), let alone the computers of non-technical people.

Oh well, Thanks anyways. Ill instead refocus my efforts into making something for the GIS team to use.

Comment: I'm quite sure that you can achieve your goal using python and gdal library (in which QGIS is based also), so you don't need to install qgis